# Docker containers have no internet access

Tags: networking, docker, manjaro

So I am recently switched to Manjaro as my daily driver on my tower and my laptop. On both I experience the same issue: Docker container can't connect to the internet. I am testing this with `docker run --rm -it alpine ping 8.8.8.8`. If I use the `--net=host` option though, so the whole command looks like `docker run --rm --net=host -it alpine ping 8.8.8.8`, the container is able to ping. But if I understand this option correctly, the containers will not be able to talk to each other, which they will have to be able to do. My kernel version is 5.2.21-1.

For the remote possibility that it matters, both computers are behind a NAT and in a network that filters (and assigns IPs) based on the MAC address of the device.

With the container running and trying to ping my `ip a` output (I blanked out actual MACs) is

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.173.136.22/16 brd 10.173.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 83012sec preferred_lft 83012sec
    inet6 fe80::48d7:85d5:4c9d:4dd/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:8e:6f:31:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.0.1/16 brd 172.31.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:8eff:fe6f:3171/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: veth65af0a1@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether b2:40:b4:8c:6c:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::b040:b4ff:fe8c:6cf1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### So far I have tried to:

Create a file `/etc/systemd/network/dockerForward.network` following [this arch wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Docker#docker0_Bridge_gets_no_IP_/_no_internet_access_in_containers) with the content

```
[Match]
Name=wlp3s0
[Network]
IPForward=true
```

Looked at `networkctl` because of [this article](https://vadosware.io/post/a-reliable-fix-to-docker-not-keeping-its-ipv4-address-on-arch/). But as the output is

```
$ networkctl
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL      SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           n/a              unmanaged 
  2 enp0s31f6        ether              n/a              unmanaged 
  3 wlp3s0           wlan               n/a              unmanaged 
  4 docker0          bridge             n/a              unmanaged
```

I suspect it is not the culprit as it is not even running.

Additionally I made sure that the IP ranges do not overlap (as specified in [this comment](https://superuser.com/a/1380836)). And when I run `$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 56fe5d704cd9` it gives me the IP `172.31.0.2`.

And for good measure, here is my `iptables -L` output:

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I am kind of at a loss here and any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, here is the output of `iptables-save -c`:

```
$ iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.3 on Fri Nov 15 10:11:51 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1299:403836]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [147:26907]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
[27:2268] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
[27:2268] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
[27:2268] -A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[27:2268] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[27:2268] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
[27:2268] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
[27:2268] -A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.3 on Fri Nov 15 10:11:51 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [107:22651]
:INPUT ACCEPT [90:18175]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7:1549]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [7:1549]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
[6:2978] -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[1:84] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.31.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

More outputs mentioned in the comments:

```
$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "53ce5b5c85f1ecd2e67118496f38141193398f5786c959305f0453ac15f96c63",
        "Created": "2019-11-16T12:36:27.244838753+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.31.0.1/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.31.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]

$ docker run --rm -it alpine ip r
default via 172.31.0.1 dev eth0 
172.31.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link  src 172.31.0.2
```

Trying to retrace where exactly the connections fails I ran

```
$ docker run -it --rm gophernet/traceroute 8.8.8.8   
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  172.31.0.1 (172.31.0.1)  0.005 ms  0.051 ms  0.016 ms
 2  xxx.xxx.xxx.1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.1)  15.092 ms  0.570 ms  0.656 ms
 3  *  *  *
 4  *  *  *
 [...]
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.136` would be my actual global address for the NAT.

```
$ ip route                               
default via 10.173.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.173.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.173.136.22 metric 600 
172.31.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.1 linkdown
```

Comment: Adding the dockerForward statement to systemd-networkd config if it is not managing Your devices will not help. Did You check ip forwarding enabled with `sysctl -a|grep forward`?

Comment: you put a part of iptables' rules (the filter table) but not all. Is your system currently doing NAT? Because it probably has to. try `iptables-save -c` instead and locate some MASQUERADE or SNAT rules. If there's none, you might know what to look for

Comment: @A.B I added the output of `iptables-save -c` to my post. It does contain the line `[1:84] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.31.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE` near the bottom. But I am not quite sure what to do with that information.

Comment: @EOhm Yes, I have checked for that before. Am I correct to assume that of the lines `net.ipv4.conf.all.bc_forwarding = 0`
`net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1`
`net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0` the ones with "bc" and "mc" in them are not relevant for me?

Comment: @be_cracked  You do have a masquerade rule, so fine, that's not the problem (and I'm out of idea)

Comment: Hmm yes I think thats ok. As long as `net.ipv4.conf.docker0.forwarding = 1` it should be ok. Did You inspect the network? (`docker network inspect bridge`) Did You check routing table in container? (`docker run --rm -it alpine ip r`)

Comment: @EOhm, `net.ipv4.conf.docker0.forwarding = 1` is indeed set as well.
I added the outputs of the commands you have pointed out. I don't really know enough to really understand them and/or know what to look for, but is this in `docker network inspect bridge` under "options" as it should be? `"com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0"`

Comment: I was up to the gateway settings in container. But they are ok and as expected on a default setup. Currently I'm a bit out t of ideas. I don't found what bc_forwarding means and I'm wondering whether You may use nftables which I don't know as You have quite recent kernel. Is `nft list ruleset` showing something? Which distro are You using there? Maybe next step could be to do some packet tracing on the interfaces (tcpdump) to find more details on where the connection breaks..

Comment: @EOhm I also came across some mentions of nft, but I don't have it installed.
My distro is Manjaro (an Arch derivative) and since the post I actually updated the kernel to 5.3.11-1, but I could downgrade it. Actually thought about the packed tracing as well, but the only way I know of is the `traceroute` package. You have a suggested way? Otherwise I will just try it with that. Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: @EOhm, I have appended the output of `docker run -it --rm gophernet/traceroute 8.8.8.8` to my post. The connection terminates when it reaches my NATed IP. Still no clue why though...

Comment: So `xxx.xxx.xxx.1` is the default gateway of Your host machine? Something that is used as point to point host route on interface `wlp3s0` (or is it like `10.173.136.1` in relation to Your interfaces address)? What does a traceroute from Your host machine shows in contrast and what is the hosts routing table? I'm wondering about the `111.31.0.1` in Your traceroute from container. That is not as expected.

Comment: For tracing I mean to start a tcpdump on Your host machine for the outgoing interfaces icmp packages with host 8.8.8.8...

Comment: I would have guessed that `xxx.xxx.xxx.1` is my default gateway, yes. But looking at the output of `ip route` (also appended to the post) it would seem as though `10.173.1.1` is my default gateway. I am not 100% sure how my network is organized in that regard because I live in a student dorm.
I will look into the tcpdumping.

Comment: The `111.31.0.1` resulted from a changed `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, which I changed just to make absolutely sure the address ranges are not interfering. Forgot to change it back in the trace. Reverted to change to the config now anyways though. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: To be sure I also ran `traceroute 8.8.8.8` on my host and the result was `1  xxx.xxx.xxx.1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.1)  2.483 ms  7.973 ms  7.938 ms [...]`. So the same address as in the container.

Comment: So [here](https://www.pastiebin.com/5dd3bb65cb21f) is the output of `tcpdump outbound` to reduce noise (it's a network with ~150 people in it after all). I also tried to clean up the log somehwat but didn't want to delete anything that might be important. Requests to dns.google (or 8.8.8.8) seem to time out.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think I am having the same issue, but on an Ubuntu server